# Design a window without a caption bar - QT Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

How can I declare a window without caption when I use QT Designer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524474/qt-hide-the-title-bar-of-a-dialog-window

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you're looking to remove window title, then the easiest way would be to set the window flags in your widget's constructor, smth like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),  //<-- this will remove the title bar
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
...
```

or call

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;
setWindowFlags(flags);
```

more details on window types here: [enum Qt::WindowType flags Qt::WindowFlags](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: So when designing a window in QT-Designer, I should just ignore the caption and treat only the client area as what will be visible?

Answer (score 2):

you didn't say which language you mean, so I say how to do it in Python with Qt : 
**First of all**, you **can't-do it** in *Qt Designer* application!

After you designed your GUI via Qt designer app, then you should add this line of 
python code to your **FILE**.**py** (generated with pyuic5) :

`MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)`